# Passing a template class as an argument to a different file class?

Tags: c++

I want to make a template class on my main.cpp then process it on another class which is from another header/cpp

Heres my code:

Main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "test.h"


template<typename B>
class foo{

};


int main() {

return 0;
}
```

test.h

```
namespace sn{
class A{
    public:
        void getint(foo<int> asd);    //error because it doesn't know foo
};
}
```

test.cpp

```
#include<iostream>
#include "test.h"

namespace sn{

void A::getint(foo<int> asd){   //error because it doesn't know foo

}    
}
```

So how can i pass an instance of a template class from or introduce "foo" from main.cpp? do i have to change my design?

Comment: Define your class template in its own header, and then include that header in the files where you need to use `foo`

Comment: Define `foo` in a header file and include that header file in all source files that want to use `foo`.

Comment: I heard that you can't define template classes on headers? can i see an example?

Comment: @CarloBrew You heard wrong, it's quite the [opposite](https://stackoverflow.com/q/495021/241631)

Comment: just a question though, where should i implement the prototypes if ill make a different header for it? do i have to make foo.cpp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The obvious method would be to move the definition of `foo` into a header as well:

foo.h:

```
template<typename B>
class foo{

};
```

test.h:

```
#include "foo.h"

namespace sn {
struct A {
    void getint(foo<int>);
};
}
```

From the looks of things, `test.cpp` would remain unchanged, and `main.cpp` would just have its definition of `foo` deleted.

Comment: I see thank you. do i have to make foo.cpp to implement the prototypes from foo.h?

Comment: @CarloBrew: at least in most typical cases, you want to put the entire implementation of a template into the header (not ideal, but such is life until modules get added to the language).

Comment: I see. so my only choice is to implement everything to the header?

Comment: @CarloBrew: It's not the only possible choice, but it is the most common one. If (for example) you know *a priori* all the types over which the template will ever be instantiated, you can move the implementations into a source file, and explicitly instantiate the template over each of those types.